# Checkbox disable enable

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I currently have a jQuery function that disables a Checkboxlist if the Parent Checkbox is unchecked and enables when It is checked.  However, the Parent checkbox is defaulted to uncheck, which I want.

This causes a problem for the code because it is enabled on pageload and only disables if you check and uncheck the parent Checkbox.

Anyone know a fix?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cbsys').bind('click', function() {
        var doEnable = ($('#cbsys:checked').length > 0);
        $('#syscbl').each(function() {
            if (doEnable) {
                $(this).attr('disabled', null);
                $(this).parents('label').removeClass('cssDisabled');
            } else {
                $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $(this).parents('label').addClass('cssDisabled');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `$('#syscbl').each`? for one element?

Comment: I think those are the other checkboxes in the "Checkboxlist"...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just cache it as a function and run it on document ready as well as on click. I also optimized your code a bit:

```
function disableCk() {
  var doEnable = $('#cbsys:checked').length; // <-- use a class
  $('#syscbl').each(function() { // <-- use a class
    var $this = $(this);
    if (doEnable) {
      $this.prop('disabled', false)
        .parents('label')
        .removeClass('cssDisabled');
    }
    else {
      $this.prop('disabled', true)
        .parents('label')
        .addClass('cssDisabled');
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  disableCk();
  $('#cbsys').on('click', disableCk);
});
```

**EDIT**

Just noticed that you seem to be using multiple ids with same name which is invalid HTML, make sure to use classes instead. I put a comment in the code, take a look above.

Comment: They are currently the ID of the cbl.  Should I create a class and place it both in the cbl control and the jquery?  Im a bit new, so i might be missing something.  It seems a bit unnecessary.

Comment: The thing is id MUST be unique, so this `$('#syscbl').each` doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Yeah, that was the way I was taught.  It was probably over compesating.  But there is only ONE that I am targeting towards.

Answer (score 1):

Just trigger your click handler immediately after binding it:

```
$('#cbsys').bind('click', function() {
    var doEnable = ($('#cbsys:checked').length > 0);
    $('#syscbl').each(function() {
    if (doEnable) {
        $(this).attr('disabled', null);
        $(this).parents('label').removeClass('cssDisabled');
    }
    else {
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $(this).parents('label').addClass('cssDisabled');
    }
}).trigger('click').trigger('click');
```

Comment: aaand -1. This would then just `check` the parent checkbox. "Parent checkbox is defaulted to uncheck, which I want."

Comment: haha, I'll remove my downvote for the edit, buuuut it's still a wee bit messy.

Comment: Good point @ahren - I guess the way to do it with minimal change to the existing code is just to trigger the click twice (as per my updated answer)... The original code is kind of weird though, I mean `$('#syscbl').each(...` doesn't make sense, and `doEnable = this.checked` would be nicer...